# Difference between applying free() on **my_vector and ***my_vector

Tags: c, pointers

I found a function that frees memory of a matrix:

```
void free_matrix(int ***matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    int row;

    if (matrix != NULL && *matrix != NULL) {
        for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            free((*matrix)[row]);
            (*matrix)[row] = NULL;
        }
        free(*matrix);
        *matrix = NULL;
    }    
}
```

I call the method like this:

```
int **my_vector = create_matrix(5, 5);
free_matrix(&my_vector, 5, 5);
```

I don't quite understand why the author decided to use `***matrix` and not `**matrix` since in my other method where I create the matrix, he is exactly doing that:

```
void fill_matrix(int **matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            matrix[row][col] = ((row + 1) * 10) + col;
        }
    }
}

int **create_matrix(int rows, int cols) {
    int row;
    int **matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof(int *));

    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        matrix[row] = malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

There must a reason why suddenly the author decided to use `int ***matrix` instead of `int **matrix`.

Comment: `int **` cannot reference a matrix, aka 2D array.

Comment: Bein a three-star programmer in C is not a compliment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author passes the address of the matrix pointer to allow the `free_matrix` matrix to reset the pointer to `NULL` in the caller's scope.  It is a precaution to prevent accesses to the matrix data after it has been freed, but if the caller made a copy of the matrix pointer, it can still invoke undefined behavior by accessing it via the copy.

As suggested by Olaf, matrices should be implemented as 2D arrays, for much simpler allocation and deallocation:

```
/* allocating a pointer to a 2D array matrix[rows][cols] filled to 0 */
int (*matrix)[cols] = calloc(sizeof(*matrix), rows);
/* free the matrix */
free(matrix); matrix = NULL;
```

But, if the sizes are not constant, the syntax required to pass these matrices as function arguments or worse to return them is not so obvious and requires a C99 compliant compiler.

To clarify the dubious advantage of the `***` approach, lets look at the more common 2 star solution:

```
void free_matrix(int **matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    int row;

    if (matrix != NULL) {
        for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            free(matrix[row]);
        }
        free(matrix);
    }    
}

int main(void) {
    int **my_vector = create_matrix(5, 5);
    fill_matrix(my_vector, 5, 5);
    free_matrix(my_vector, 5, 5);
    if (my_vector) {
        /* trying to access the freed data will invoke undefined behavior */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the code above, `my_vector` is not reset to `NULL` by `free_matrix`, so the programmer might try to access it and invoke undefined behavior (crash or anything else), whereas in the posted code, the three star `free_matrix` would reset `my_vector` to `NULL` which can be easily tested.

Comment: An `int **` cannot reference a matrix, resp. 2D array.

Comment: @Olaf: you are a bit too picky: `matrix` is not defined in the C Standard as a 2D array, it is appropriate to use the word matrix to refer to a structure that implements the eponymous mathematical object. Matrices with dimensions unknown at compile time cannot be implemented as 2D arrays in C89, but can be implemented as arrays of pointers to arrays of cells, as is the case for the OP.

Comment: Excuse me. If we use the parameter `int **matrix`is it not possible to set it free by `free(matrix)`? That looks like doing the same just on another way

Comment: The question is not tagged C89 or C90. The C tag implies the current version is available or at least C99. And no, I'm not picky. The construct with `int **` has a very different memory layout and different performance characteristics (to the good or the bad). It is most times used just because the user is not aware how to properly declare the pointer to 2D array.Worse: many people think that **is** a 2D array and there is no other way, including long-term C programmers. Which results in tripple- and more star programmers.

Comment: @DennisvonEich: Thanks, your last comment exactly supports my last comment (pre-last sentence).

Comment: @DennisvonEich: you can free the data by passing `matrix` instead of `&matrix` (assuming you change `free_matrix` accordingly), but the latter ensures that the variable `matrix` in the caller's scope is automatically set to `NULL` after the data it pointed to has been freed.

Comment: @Olaf: your statement *An int ** cannot reference a matrix, resp. 2D array* is still too strong.  I agree a matrix should be implemented as a 2D array, for much simpler allocation and deallocation: `int (*matrix)[cols] = calloc(sizeof(**matrix), cols * rows);` and `free(matrix); matrix = NULL;`.  But this is beyond many programmers' skill level and their teachers' too.

Comment: @chqrlie I nearly got it now. But can you point out why is it not automatically set to `NULL` in the other case?

Comment: `sizeof(**matrix), cols * rows` -> `sizeof(*matrix), rows`. If you don't need `calloc`, it is the usual `sizeof(*matrix) * rows`. I agree about the skill-levels. But that is imo no reason not to point people towards this. Actually, if explained properly, even beginners grasp it quite well (and en passant understand pointers&arrays much better).

Comment: Another note: `calloc` _zeroes_ the memory. That is not necessarily the same as setting all pointer to _null pointers_. _null pointers_ do not neceessarily have a representation of all-bits-zero.

Comment: @Olaf: excellent suggestion for the allocation size, my version would easily fail if `rows` and `cols` are `int` and cause arithmetic overflow for large but possible allocations such as 65536*65536.

Comment: @chqrlie (and any occasional reader): I just applied the simple rule to always use `sizeof(*pointer_on_left_side_of_assignment_for_the_malloc)`. That works without further thinking. OTOH, `calloc` takes `size_t` for both arguments. This is the correct type for array indexing, so if you use correct types consequently you are always on the safe side however you combine size and number of entries.